# Eevee vs Cycles render issues

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shrinkwrap

I am rendering a bottle and running into an issue with a shrink-wrapped label (image as plane) when switching from Eevee to Cycles.

Here is the render through Eevee. As you can see the label is not distorted.

[image]

Here is the render through Cycles. As you can see the label is now distorted and there is a dark streak down the bottle in the distorted area.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is the shader and texture map [![shader and texture][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhpbY.jpg

Comment: That's not the shader for the label, which is what you're concerned with.

Comment: Apologies! Here is the shader for the label [![shader and texture][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Ywb.jpg

Comment: Then I'd suspect that Cycles is accurately presenting your alpha channel, while Eevee is not, which is expected.  Alpha Blend on top of Alpha Blend is usually a bad idea.  If you want Eevee to show you something closer to your Cycles representation, use Alpha Hashed (for both.)  If your glass is a refraction object, this still will probably be incorrect.  And make sure your label is *outside* of your bottle, not inside.  More info would require a file, with packed textures; this is not a function just of shader, but geometry matters too.

Comment: Thank you! My offset had reset to 0 and changing from alpha blend to alpha hash worked perfect.